# How can I get the title of the selected UISegment in a UISegmentControl?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

The class of the selected segment is shown as UISegment, which I can't find a class reference to. Surely there is a way to access the title associated with the selected index?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`UISegmentedControl`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html) documentation:

`NSString * selectedTitle = [mySegmentedControl titleForSegmentAtIndex:[mySegmentedControl selectedSegmentIndex]];`